# GoogleTagManager: Product revenue is zero from iOS

Tags: google-analytics, static, in-app-purchase, google-tag-manager

I sent to GTM the following data:

```
ecommerce =     {
    add =         {
        products =             (
                            {
                id = PPP011;
                name = PPP011;
                price = "0.99";
                quantity = 1;
            }
        );
    };
    currencyCode = USD;
    purchase =         {
        actionField =             {
            id = 1234565614;
            revenue = "0.99";
        };
        products =             (
                            {
                id = PPP011;
                name = PPP011;
                price = "13.99";
                quantity = 1;
            }
        );
    };
};
event = purchase;
eventAction = "<null>";
eventLabel = "<null>";
userID = 123456;
```

And in reports GTM I can see only the Product Revenue **0**.

I've found the following potentials problem:
- wrong currency code
- bad transaction ID
- string type in values
- the same id previously sent to GTM

Can someone help with any ideas or something else for resolving this issue? I was able to start see this problem from begin of march 2016.

Comment: How I can see from Analytics it happens sometimes. I can't find dependency. But many items have perfect revenue(more than 95%).

Comment: Language was installed Russian on device. But application didn't support its. Have someone ideas how correlate language with zero revenue?